# Strong Pointer causing a heap corruption on application closing when std::vector is present

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap-memory, smart-pointers

I am getting a strange heap corruption error during the application close where if a "std::vector" is present in my code, AND I am deleted my "ref_count" variable. If I don't have an std::vector, there is no crash. If there is a std::vector and I don't delete the ref_count (causing a memory leak), then there is a heap crash. I am made my test case as small as possible, but unfortunately it is too big for here so it is located at http://codepad.org/USIPjPHJ . Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be the problem?

I will get a crash with the heap exception of this in my output windows.

---

HEAP[CrashTest.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 6d4c30 modified at 6d4c58 after it was freed
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in CrashTest.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in CrashTest.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while CrashTest.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

---

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (tried on non SP1 also) but that should not be causing the issue.

Comment: I accept answers if they are on topic to my question and if they are correct. If you check my questions and their responses, I don't always get this.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating your member counters? That doesn't look right.

Comment: @chadb: As someone pointed out in a response to a similar answer you gave, it's up to you to provide explanation for why those answers aren't sufficient, and to ask for clarification or additional information. Bad answers are more often than not the fault of the person asking the questions.

Comment: I do supply more information, however, without a proper way to bump they just get forgotten about. I would like to submit answers and support the community, but only the right ones.

Comment: @ twsaef: so the same reference counter can be shared across strong_ptr's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
strong_ref<int> reg1;
```

sets *ref_count to 0 (because ptr == NULL), then this line:

```
strong_ref<int> copy1(reg1);
```

increments *ref_count to 1.

On exit, the destructor is called twice (once for reg1, once for copy1). The first time, *ref_count is decremented to 0 and ref_count is deallocated, leaving a dangling reference for the second time.

Comment: Interesting, what would the fix for this be?

Comment: *ref_count is supposed to be the number of references to the object pointed to by ptr (0 if ptr == NULL), therefore, increment and decrement *ref_count only if ptr != NULL.

Comment: Even with "if(ptr) { ++(*ref_count); }" in the copy constructor, I still get the crash. Is this what you meant?

Comment: After a bit more thought, I think that it would still cause a problem in the destructor because you wouldn't know how many references there were to ref_count. The simplest solution would be to always increment and decrement *ref_count. *ref_count would be the number of references to ref_count and the object pointed to by ptr (or ptr may be NULL, but that's irrelevant here).

Comment: Even while doing that there is still a crash, do you happen to have a working example of that?

Comment: I changed `if(ptr) { *ref_count = 1; }` to `*ref_count = 1;`. No crash.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Even with that I am getting a heap crash. can you upload the post to codepad?